# Syntax for launching many async tasks in c#

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

I'm having trouble using the new async/await tools in c#. Here is my scenario:

```
static async Task<bool> ManageSomeRemoteTask(int Id, bool flag)
{
    var result = await serviceClient.AuthenticateIdAsync(Id);
    [... Setup Some Data ...]
    await serviceClient.LongAndSlowRemoteCallAsync(Data);
}

static void SendATonOfJunkToSomeWebServiceThatDoesntSupportBatches
{
    var myTasks = Dictionary<int, Task<bool>>();
    while(IdsLeftToProcess > 0 )
    {
      Task<bool> t = ManageSomeRemoteTask(Id, true);
      myTasks.Add(IdsLeftToProcess ,t);
      myTasks[IdsLeftToProcess].Start();
      IdsLeftToProcess --;
    }

    Task.WaitAll(myTasks.Values.ToArray()); //Wait until they are all done
    [... Report statistics ...]
}
```

I have 1 problem in that when I try running this, I get an InvalidOperationException on the Start() with the error message "*Start may not be called on a promise-style task.*" This error message doesn't seem to come up in Google or Bing so I'm not sure what it means. This is my number one concern, how to get this to run. I also tried TaskFactory.StartNew() but didn't understand how to pass parameters to my method that way.

Comment: Despite my opinion that the line shouldn't be there at all, you'd save a bit of time by not pulling something you've already got a reference to out of the dictionary... as such `myTasks[IdsLeftToProcess].Start();` would have been better represented by `t.Start()` (if it were necessary in the first place)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Tasks returned by async methods are always *hot* i.e. they are created in Running state. Try to remove task.Start() from you code - it should fix it.

A quote from [Stephen Toub's Async/Await FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/10293335.aspx):

> Do I need to “Start” Tasks created by methods marked as “async”?
>
> > No.  Tasks returned from TAP methods are “hot”, meaning the tasks represent operations that are already in-progress.  Not only do you not need to call “.Start()” on such tasks, but doing so will fail if you try.  For more details, see FAQ on Task.Start.

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart - added a reference, thanks for pointing out

Comment: It's easy to miss little tid-bits like that information. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to start the Tasks returned by async method calls. They're started by default.

Comment: Actually, you *can't* start them.

Comment: Isn't that what the question's all about?

Comment: You said you don't need to start them, that implies you can if you want to. But that's not true.

Comment: Hence, the InvalidOperationException :)

Comment: I encountered this issue when I was mocking the response of an 'async' method. Because the task I returned was cold, but the one created by the actual async method was hot.