# How do I create a Task that uses await inside the body that behaves the same as the synchronous version when Wait is called?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, .net-4.5, async-await

I have some code that creates a task that does some slow work like this:

```
public static Task wait1()
{
    return new Task(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting...");
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        Console.WriteLine("Done!");
    });
}
```

In the real implementation, the Thread.Sleep will actually be a web service call. I would like to change the body of the method can use await (so it does not consume a thread during the network access/sleep). My first attempt (based on shotgun-debugging the compile errors) was this:

```
public static Task wait2()
{
    return new Task(async () =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting...");
        await Task.Delay(10000);
        Console.WriteLine("Done!");
    });
}
```

However; this task doesn't seem to behave the same as the first one, because when I call .Wait() on it; it returns immediately.

Below is a full sample (console app) showing the differences (the app will end immediately when the second task starts).

What do I need to do so that I can call Start and Wait on a Task which happens to have code using await inside it? The tasks are queued and executed later by an agent, so it's vital that the task is not auto-started.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var w1 = wait1();
        w1.Start();
        w1.Wait(); // This waits 110 seconds

        var w2 = wait2();
        w2.Start();
        w2.Wait(); // This returns immediately
    }

    public static Task wait1()
    {
        return new Task(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting...");
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            Console.WriteLine("Done!");
        });
    }

    public static Task wait2()
    {
        return new Task(async () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting...");
            await Task.Delay(10000);
            Console.WriteLine("Done!");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Why make a `new Task` at all? Why not make the outer method `async` and have it return the `Task` automatically? That is, `static async Task wait3() { Console.WriteLine("..."); await Task.Delay(10000); Console.WriteLine("..."); }`

Comment: @EricLippert I tried this; but it seems to behave differently... Calling `.Start()` throws `System.InvalidOperationException: Start may not be called on a promise-style task.`. My tasks are going into a queue to be called later; so I need to be able to start them later.

Comment: Is your goal to halt wait1/2 at the await line until Start has been called?  I ask this based on your comment to @fcuesta that "I need to be able to call Start later."  If that is the case, I think the question needs updated with the execution you're hoping for.

Comment: @RyanCromwell My goal is to have a method that uses await inside it's implementation (to save threads when a task has a network call) that behaves *exactly the same* externally as the one that doesn't. Eg. no work is done until I call `Start`, and then `Wait` should block until the entire body is completed.

Comment: @RyanCromwell I've updated the question a little; hope this is clearer!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems like this isn't possible! See [alexm's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236009/syntax-for-launching-many-async-tasks-in-c-sharp):

> Tasks returned by async methods are always *hot* i.e. they are created in Running state.

:-(

I've worked around this by making my agent queue `Func<Task>s` instead, and the overload that receives a task simply queues `() => task`. Then; when de-queing a task, I check if it's not running, and if so, start it:

```
var currentTask = currentTaskFunction();
if (currentTask.Status == TaskStatus.Created)
    currentTask.Start();
```

It seems a little clunky to have to do this (if this simple workaround works; why the original restriction on async methods always being created hot?), but it seems to work for me :-)

Comment: Actually, that's exactly what you want to do. In the `async` world, a `Task` is already running, so if you want the ability to *start* a task at a later time, the correct type to use is `Func<Task>`.

Comment: @StephenCleary I just found your blog post that does this, and is almost an exact copy of what I was writing! http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/returning-early-from-aspnet-requests.html Though my agent sits in a loop processing the queue one-at-a-time!

Comment: I can see that it'd be confusing if async methods returned tasks that weren't started; it's just a shame that it makes it not-obvious how to use await in delayed tasks.

Comment: The question of whether to provide a syntax for cold tasks was hotly debated during the design of the feature. Obviously the hot-only side won.

Comment: Yeah, I can understand that, and it's a bit of an edge case. Probably easier to make code that needs this explicit than have some ambiguity elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You could write this as:

```
public static async Task Wait2()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting...");
    await Task.Delay(10000);
    Console.WriteLine("Done!");
}
```

In general, it's rarely a good idea to ever use `new Task` or `new Task<T>`.  If you must launch a task using the ThreadPool instead of using the `async`/`await` language support to compose one, you should use `Task.Run` to start the task.  This will schedule the task to run (which is important, tasks should always be "hot" by conventions).

Note that doing this will make it so you don't have to call `Task.Start`, as well.

Comment: I'm deliberately calling `Start`. In my app, the tasks are "queued" and processed later. I'd like to be able to use await to free up the threads, as nearly every task queued will have a web service call in the middle; using await would be nice :-)

Answer (score 1):

To help you understand this realize that async / await essentially does not create a new thread but rather it schedules that portion of code to be ran at an available point in time.

When you create the new Task(async () => ...) you have a task that run an async method.  When that inner async method hits an await the 'new Task' is considered complete because the rest of it has been scheduled.  To help you understand better place some code (a lot if wanted) in the 'new Task' before the await command.  It will all execute before the application terminates and once await is reached that task will believe it has completed.  It then returns and exits the application.

The best way to avoid this is to not place any task or async methods inside of your task.

Remove the async keyword and the await keyword from the method and it will work as expected.

This is the same as creating a callback if you're familiar with that.

```
void MethodAsync(Action callback)
{
     //...some code
     callback?.Invoke();
}

//using this looks like this.
MethodAsync(() => { /*code to run when complete */});
```

//This is the same as

```
Task MethodAsync()
{
     //... some code here
}

//using it

await MethodAsync();
/*code to run when complete */
```

The thing to understand is that you're creating a new task within a task basically.  So the inner 'callback' is being created at the await keyword.

You're code looks like this..

```
void MethodAsync(Action callback)
{
     //some code to run
     callback?.Invoke();  // <- this is the await keyword
     //more code to run.. which happens after we run whoever is
     //waiting on callback
}
```

There's code missing obviously.  If this doesn't make sense please feel free to contact me and I'll assist.  async / await (meant to make things simpler) is a beast to wrap your head around at first.  Afterward you get it then it'll probably be your favorite thing in c# since linq. :P

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public async static Task wait2()
{
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting...");
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("Done!");
}
```

But we aware that the task is already started so you don't have to call start:

```
var w2 = wait2();
//w2.Start();
w2.Wait();
```

I think the problem with your wait2 function is that is creating 2 task, the one in `new Task(...)` and another in `Task.Delay()`. You are waiting for the first one, but you are not waiting for the inner one.

Comment: I need to be able to call `Start` later, so this won't work :( I suspect you may be right about having multiple tasks, but it seems confusing to me that the outer task doesn't encompass the whole block of work :(